# Multiple Database with single Website using Database Overwrite the Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have Multi tenancy Web Application. I want to publish one website which support Multiple Database where Connection String save in Database

Example:

Login User-A --> Connect to Database-A
Login User-B --> Connect to Database-B

master Database save User and Connection String.

But my problem is when User A Login to application it working correctly(using DB-A) once user-B login some how it overwrite the Connection string. Then Both User show the DB-B data.

Can you please help

Thanks

Comment: Poor architecture.

Comment: and for 100 users you have 100 databases ? - and when you update the program (and the database), how you going to make 100 databases update with out bugs and errors ?

Comment: We are not going to update our database very often .. 
But Program Could be or then you have better solution ?

Comment: Why don't you use Design Pattern? On Application start Check which User is logged in and Use that user Connection String. You Could add connection strings in app.config file also.

Answer (score -1):

You can use session for assigning connection string based on type of user. On User logout, close the session. This will stop values from being overwritten.

Comment: Thanks Dheeraj  for reply 
Its means for Every Query /or database hit i need to Open and close the connection ..would it effect  on performance ?

Comment: No It shouldn't. I had a project developed with n number of times connection opened and closed in each page. Make sure it closes at end.